# Which is better option Create/Save for Activity and Circle?

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-behavior, ux-field

I want to create an Activity as well as Circle for networking. Which button will be suitable 'Create' or 'Save'.

[image]

Comment: By "Activity", I am guessing you mean an event, right? And what kind of "Circle" are you talking about?

Comment: yes it's an event an circle is like google plus circle

Comment: So, a user picks a category and an event date and time and he not only creates an event but he also automatically becomes a member of a circle which is named after that category?! Is that so? The definition of a "circle" is too vague at the moment for us. It would help if you can expand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **create** when you are creating a **new item**.

Use **save** when you are making changes to an **existing item**.

It's clear from the language that 'create' is a new item of some sort, and succinctly communicates that what you are about to do will result in a new record being created, but that if you don't, that record will not exist.

Similarly, when using 'save', it is clear that if you were to cancel the operation, the record will still exist, but any changes you have made will not exist.

Any deviation from these standards will likely result in confusion as your actions and the description of them are misaligned.

Answer (score 0):

"Create" seems more logical here since it would imply that an event has been created and saved(obviously). "Save" would be too bland for the purpose.

Alternatively, you can also go with "Create and Save", if you really want to ensure that the user gets it and want to be too direct.